# accessing item in a python loop with conditions

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, if-statement

say i have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
data = [
{'views' : views,
 'ratings' : ratings,
 'link' : link
},
{'views' : views,
 'ratings' : ratings,
 'link' : link
},
{'views' : views,
 'ratings' : ratings,
 'link' : link
},
{'views' : views,
 'ratings' : ratings,
 'link' : link
},
...
...
]
```

how do I get the link of item that has  views greater than 500000 AND ratings greater than 80?
the problem here is whatever I tried, it basically prints out all the links without going through the conditions.

Comment: so what have you tried!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension!

```
[each['link'] for each in data if int(each['ratings'])>80 and int(each['views'])>500000 ]
```

Note - if you aint sure about the variable type, typecast it to integer before comparison!

You have two conditions!

- views > 500000
- ratings > 80

Since your data is a list of dictionaries, iterate through the list with items(dict) as `each` and get the `list` key from that list!

Hope it helps!

Comment: still not working as intended. it gets all the links without meeting the conditions.

Comment: is your views and rating variable a string or an integer?

Comment: I've added the edits for typecasting the variable to integer!

Answer (score 1):

`links = [item['link'] for item in data if item['views'] > 500000]`

This question is, too simple to be suitable for this website.

Comment: i have problem printing only the item that meet the condition. This, again, gets all the link in the list.

Comment: @TianchengXu no it doesn't. It results in all items that satisfy `item['views'] > 500000`